# How do I get JavaScript to recognise when a wordpress link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

For my site: http://rydalmereprestige.com.au/

I am trying to implement a popup banner using JavaScript and css.

I have managed to get the script to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/qdor8usL/3/

```
$('.menu-item-21').click(function () {
    $("#popups_about").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $("#popups_services").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#popups_quote").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#popups_contact").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#popups_about").slideUp(0)
        .delay(2000)
        .slideDown(1000);
});

$('.menu-item-486').click(function () {
    $("#popups_about").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#popups_services").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $("#popups_quote").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#popups_contact").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#popups_services").slideUp(0)
        .delay(2000)
        .slideDown(1000);
});

$('.menu-item-733').click(function () {
    $("#popups_about").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#popups_services").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#popups_quote").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $("#popups_contact").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#popups_quote").slideUp(0)
        .delay(2000)
        .slideDown(1000);
});

$('.menu-item-17').click(function () {
    $("#popups_about").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#popups_services").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#popups_quote").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#popups_contact").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $("#popups_contact").slideUp(0)
        .delay(2000)
        .slideDown(1000);
});
```

but when I implement it into my site - it just won't show.

The premise is for each menu item clicked at the top - a different banner is supposed to pop up.

For reference, the above code is implemented within the theme files:

```
header.php - javascript
footer.php - div tags
style.css - css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code like this and it should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // $('.menu-item-21').click....

});
```

The problem was that the code was executed before the `.menu-item-#` were created.

Answer (score 0):

If it is working on jsfiddle but not on your site, it is likely to be an external factor on your website.

Have you referenced the correct jquery library?